# Basis for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, integer-lattices

Motivation: To gain a more thorough understanding of how bases transform under a mapping. To increase understanding of general linear algebra concepts.

Consider a lattice, $Λ = \Bbb Zv_1 +\Bbb Zv_2,$ in $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard basis.

Consider as well, a lattice $\zeta,$ in $\Bbb R^2_*$ fixing $(1,1)$ as the origin (to get from $\Lambda$ to $\zeta$ I exponentiated each coordinate). So $(n,k) \in \Lambda$ maps to $(e^n,e^k)\in \zeta.$

> What is a basis for $\zeta?$

Is it just $\zeta=\Bbb Zw_1+\Bbb Zw_2$, such that $w_1=(e,0)$ and $w_2=(0,e)?$ Here $e\approx 2.718.$

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "fixing $(1,1)$ as the origin". Also, what reason to you have to believe that the constant $e$ has anything to do with this problem?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I just mean "choosing (1,1)" as the origin because $1w=w$ for $w \in \zeta.$

Comment: and to map from the vector space $\Lambda$ to $\zeta$ I exponentiated each coordinate in the space. Thus i think the basis in $\Lambda$ lifts to the basis in $\zeta$

Comment: What does $+$ mean in $\mathbb R_*^2$? Shouldn't it be some multiplication instead?

Comment: i considered that but couldn't figure out how to make it work @md2perpe

Comment: @geocalc33 If $\zeta$ refers specifically to the lattice obtained by "exponentiating" the elements of $\Lambda$, then this should be made clear in the question. In any case, this question could only begin to make sense if the relationship between $\Lambda$ and $\zeta$ is made explicit.

Comment: @geocalc Also, any motivation or other context for this question would be helpful

Comment: okay ben thanks

Comment: How about $\zeta = w_1^{\mathbb Z} \odot w_2^{\mathbb Z},$ where $w_1=(a,1)$ and $w_2=(1,b)$ for some $a,b\neq 1,$ and $(x_1,y_1)\odot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2)$?

Comment: And of course, $w^{\mathbb Z} = \{ w^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$

Comment: could you make an answer @md2perpe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $\zeta = w_1^{\mathbb Z} \odot w_2^{\mathbb Z},$ where $w_1=(a,1)$ and $w_2=(1,b)$ for some $a,b>0; a,b\neq 1,$ and $(x_1,y_1)\odot(x_2,y_2)=(x_1 x_2, y_1 y_2)$ and $w^{\mathbb Z} = \{ w^n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: can you think of a way to write this vector space as a complex vector space?

Comment: First note that the vector space here has multiplication as "addition" and power as "multiplication with scalar". We can always make a real vector space $V$ into a complex vector space $V^{\mathbb C}$ via a tensor product, $\mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} V$:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification

Comment: could you add this part to your answer please, if it's not too much effort?

Comment: Just copy the comment or also expand on how complexification works?

Comment: could you add how this specific complexification of $\zeta$ would work?

Comment: say you take elements of the vector space and added them together even though + might not mean anything in $\Bbb R^2_*$